# $n$ players of paper scissor rock

Tags: discrete-mathematics, game-theory

Suppose there are $n$ players $(3\leq{n})$ showing Paper, Scissor or Rock 
simultaneously. If there is no winner then there is no payoff to any player. If 
there are winners and losers (e.g. $k$ players play Rock and $(n-k)$ players play Scissor), the losers will pay $\${1}$ each for the winners to divide evenly. 
Find a strategic equilibrium for this game.

I need some advice for this question.

Comment: A person can be both a winner and a loser, so you need to be careful here. For example, in a three person game, if each player picks a different options, they are all winners against one player and losers against another.

Comment: yeah that's why i find it very confusing!

Comment: But the point is, your choice of language is confusing. For example, "If there is no winner..." vaguely implies that there can be only one winner. You also say, "the losers will pay $1 eacch for the winners to divide evenly." Does that mean if I pick rock, my dollar is split amongst all people who picked paper, or does it mean that my dollar is split up by all people who beat anybody, potentially including myself (since somebody might have picked scissors.)

Comment: The former, so if 3 players picked different choices, there is no net loss of profit for each player.

Comment: Of course, that's true for the latter as well. The real question is, what happens when four players play and two pick rock, one picks paper, and one picks scissors.

Comment: the paper earns a net of 1 and each rock player losses a net of .5.  Mr. Scissors effectively losses/wins nothing.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, Kaine's reply is correct!

Comment: An equilibrium is for every player to play uniformly at random. (Notice if others are doing so, I get the same expected payoff from playing any action or distribution over actions, by symmetry.) But maybe a more interesting question is "find all equilibria".

Comment: Hi usul, that means i play a mixed strategy, each with probability 1/3? How do we show that this is indeed a strategic equilibrium?

Comment: @Alan: Yes! To show this, we just have to show that, if everyone else plays (1/3, 1/3, 1/3), then it maximizes my expected utility to play this strategy too. If everyone else is playing this uniformly mixed strategy, then my expected payoff is the same whether I play scissors, paper, or rock. (This must be true because they are all symmetric: If I rename the strategies, the probabilities and payoffs don't change.) So I actually will get an expected payoff of zero no matter what I do. So playing uniformly randomly (1/3, 1/3, 1/3) maximizes my expected payoff (so does every other strategy!).

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out and explained in the comments, the strategy profile in which all players choose their move uniformly at random forms an equilibrium. For $n\ge6$ there are many more equilibria; every strategy profile containing at least two pure strategies for each move forms an equilibrium, since there will be no payoff if only one player deviates. I believe these are the only equilibria, but I have no proof for that.